# How can I supplement a portable generator during peak load.

Tags: capacitor, inverter, generator, load

I'm contemplating purchasing a 2000W generator, to power some of my tools. One potential issue i that I have a saw that pulls 2500 W at startup and then 1800 w to run. Seems to my that as the generator runs, it's creating surplus power, and it's only those peak loads that overwhelm it. Would it possible to hook up some sort of large capacitor or power storage device, to supplement the the generator during those peak times? would a battery array and power invert potentially work?

Comment: It will be much cheaper and easier to buy a generator that can handle the load. I will mention that there are several models of Honda generators that use inverter technology. They are expensive, but they can be run in parallel to generate extra power. Most generators cannot be run in parallel.

Comment: good point, I suppose that it's easier just to get a bigger generator

Comment: The generator does not actually produce surplus power- the torque required by the generator to keep it spinning at the same speed increases as the load increases, that means that the engine has to be given more fuel per unit time (via an automatic throttle opening or whatever). It simply has the **capacity** to create more power than what is being used at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Member mkeith makes a good point - you can use another induction motor to supplement starting current requirements.

However, you actually want to use a fairly large motor, or a smaller motor with a heavy flywheel attached to the shaft.  It is the rotational energy contained in the spinning rotor and flywheel that provides the extra surge current capability.

Fairly large motor, to me, is anywhere from 1 to 5 HP.

Also note that this extra motor *MUST* be an induction motor, not a brushed motor.

A really quick way to try this is to use a decently-sized bench grinder with dual 8" wheels.  The grinding wheels act like flywheels and pretty much every bench grinder that I've seen since I was a kid uses induction motors.

It's certainly worth a try.

Comment: Here is the saw that I wish to run http://amzn.to/1IIbbCm and here is the generator I was looking at http://amzn.to/1ySKSt5

Comment: Thanks, Dwayne. To the OP, I may be out of line here, but 42% of the amazon reviews for that generator are 1 star reviews. I would not buy it. But I actually think a 2000 W generator will run that saw OK, as long as it can supply the start-up power. That saw will only draw 15 Amps if it is worked very hard. So if you hear the saw motor bogging down, that is a sign that you need to go easy (make the cut more slowly). Most cuts will be no problem.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't just add power to the generator.
The engine and the generator are both designed to deliver a defined number of kilowatts at full load.  There is usually a short term surge rating of 10 to 25% of the continuous rating, but that is for very short durations (and might be smaller for 'budget' generator sets).

Capacitors can't help you with AC at all.  Your best bet might be to look at a reduced voltage start solution for your saw, you didn't describe what the motor on the saw is, but I'm guessing it is a single phase AC motor... Not much going to help that, but you could potentially replace it with a DC motor and a small motor speed controller (drive) which would let it ramp up more slowly.

Possibly you could even just simply add a clutch to the motor.  Let the motor start first, then engage the clutch to start the saw.

Comment: If it is a table saw, it is probably a single-phase induction motor. But if it is a portable saw, it is probably a series wound motor. Capacitor start single-phase motors have very high start up current requirements. But series wound motors, less so. If the quoted startup and run power are correct, I would guess it is series wound.

Comment: I have read in some of the tool forums that some people turn on a smaller, unloaded induction motor first. After it starts up, they turn on the larger tool. The spinning induction motor acts like a supplemental generator to help start the larger motor.